# short php code for random number string, 5 chars

Tags: php, random, numbers

I'm having a problem, im trying to generate a 5 or 7 characters long number code with php,
but the following code does include letters, i only need numbers, thanks in advance

```
$newgid = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,9),5);
```

Comment: Do the generated numbers have to be unique though?

Comment: If you only want numbers, why not just `random_int(10000, 99999)` (PHP 7 and above) or `mt_rand(10000, 99999)` (PHP 5.6 and below)? If you *do* want letters as well, something like [`Random::alphanumericString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random) is both more efficient and more secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd simply use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand) as follows:

```
<?php
$a = '';
for ($i = 0; $i<7; $i++) 
{
    $a .= mt_rand(0,9);
}
echo $a;
?>
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/VkqOmn82)

Answer (score 5):

I would use `rand()` to generate number between 0 and 99999 and treat it as string.

```
$newgid = sprintf('%05d', rand(0, 99999));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to generate a 5 digit code quite easily, and I am sure you can work out from here how to make it 7 digits long.

```
$string='';
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $string.=rand(0,9);
}
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function randomPrefix($length=5) {       
        $random = "";
        srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
        $data = "0123456789";
       // $data = "A0B1C2DE3FG4HIJ5KLM6NOP7QR8ST9UVW0XYZ";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $random .= substr($data, (rand() % (strlen($data))), 1);
        }

        return $random;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that the numbers start from 10000 instead of zero, this is the shortest way:

```
mt_rand(10000, 99999)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function createPin($len){
    $maxNbrStr = str_repeat('9',$len);
    $maxNbr = intval($maxNbrStr);
    $n = mt_rand(0, $maxNbr);
    $pin = str_pad($n, $len, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $pin;
}
```

Here's a short & sweet function that will produce a string of numbers at the desired length.

Answer (score 1):

To future readers who come across this, I would recommend something like the following:

```
function generateNumericString(INT $len, STRING $str = '') {
    if (strlen($str) < $len) {
        return generateNumericString($len, $str . random_int(0, 9));
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Rather than using a loop, the function above uses recursion; it calls itself continuously, adding a single digit to the string, until the string length reaches the specified value. Anywhere and anytime you want you can generate a string of any length (i.e. 5) simply by calling:

```
generateNumericString(5);
```

Additionally, this method allows for the first digit in the sequence to include 0.

Although I prefer the first method, if you know you will absolutely never need more than 5 numbers in the string you can technically achieve the same thing with:

```
$n = substr(random_int(100000, 199999), 1);
```

This generates a 6 digit integer, then casts it as a string and returns everything after the first digit.  Removing the first digit preserves 0 as a possible first character.

EDIT:  [`random_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) is used in place of other methods to ensure generated numbers are [cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).